# Pygame multiple monitor

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to get the value of the current monitor size in my application.
I'm on ubuntu 16.04 with GNOME.
The problem is that I've got the netbook monitor and an external monitor so if I try doing something like:

```
info_object = pygame.display.Info() # info_object.current_w / info_object.current_h
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((info_object.current_w, info_object.current_h))
```

I get that the width of the screen is netbook monitor + external monitor so a resolution like:

> (3286, 1080)

So my other try is to get information about monitor using pygame.display.list_modes() in order to get some of display resolution settigns but I get a list like:

> [(3286, 1080), (1366, 768), (1360, 768), (1024, 768), (960, 720),
>   (960, 600), (960, 540), (928, 696), (896, 672), (840, 525), (800,
>   600), (800, 512), (720, 450), (700, 525), (680, 384), (640, 512),
>   (640, 480), (576, 432), (512, 384), (400, 300), (320, 240)]

But still don't know what is the current "active" monitor.
If I open my program in my netbook monitor I expect to get the resolution of that monitor, instead if I open it in the external one I expect to have that resolution not one plus other.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Shoot, sorry, I did not test my code.  Note sure if it is even available with pygame (i.e. pygame with sdl1), I will try to make something withh xrandr, grep, sed that spits out the screen resolution for my own purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use x11 utilities through shell.  I have the following script that outputs the active screen width and height (the screen where mouse cursor is).  You may need to install `xdotool`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
## find the resolution of the active screen
## based on Adam Bowen's solution at:
## https://superuser.com/questions/603528/how-to-get-the-current-monitor-resolution-or-monitor-name-lvds-vga1-etc
##
OFFSET_RE="[+-]([-0-9]+)[+-]([-0-9]+)"
# find offset in window data in form 143x133-0+0

# Get mouse position
pos=($(xdotool getmouselocation | sed -r "s/^x:([[:digit:]]+) y:([[:digit:]]+).*/\1 \2/p"))

# Loop through each screen and compare the offset with the window
# coordinates.
while read name width height xoff yoff
do
  if [ "${pos[0]}" -ge "$xoff" \
    -a "${pos[1]}" -ge "$yoff" \
    -a "${pos[0]}" -lt "$(($xoff+$width))" \
    -a "${pos[1]}" -lt "$(($yoff+$height))" ]
  then
      monitor=$name
      screenw=$width
      screenh=$height
  fi
done < <(xrandr | grep -w connected |
  sed -r "s/^([^ ]*).*\b([-0-9]+)x([-0-9]+)$OFFSET_RE.*$/\1 \2 \3 \4 \5/" |
  sort -nk4,5)

# If we found a monitor, echo it out, otherwise print an error.
if [ ! -z "$monitor" ]
then
    # found monitor
    echo $screenw $screenh
    exit 0
else
    # could not find monitor
    exit 1
fi
```

In python, I have the following code:

```
res = subprocess.run("./activescreen", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
if(res.returncode == 0):
    wh = res.stdout.split(b' ')
    screenw = int(wh[0])
    screenh = int(wh[1])
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((screenw, screenh), pg.RESIZABLE)
```

You can probably do some of what I did in shell in python instead and only call `xdotool` and `xrandr` directly from python.

Comment: Not sure.  You can probably do what xdotool does directly through x11 api (check out python xlib).  For sure, you can sip the full output into python and do the grep/sed stuff there.